# Is it possible call stored procedure in php fetch dynamic columns and results?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I create pivot using stored procedure, but i don't know how to automatically fetch all columns and results in PHP.

This is my stored procedure pivot result in phpmyadmin or/and mysql workbench

```
| MEMBER     | 05/07/2017 | 06/07/2017 | 07/07/2017 | 08/07/2017 |
| Accounting | 12         | 0          | 20         | 10         |
| Officer    | 1          | 20         | 4          | 8          |
| Support    | 10         | 1          | 0          | 30         |
```

Note: member and date can more than this example.

But in PHP i can't fetch all data like above and i need to type static like $data['05/07/2017'] ...

Here the script :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
require_once('connection.php');
$smt = $conn->query('CALL SalesRecord()');
$row = $smt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<tr>
<td><?php print_r(json_encode(explode("",$row['0']))); ?><br></td>
<td><?php print_r($row['1']); ?><br></td> #here i need to static input
<td><?php print_r($row['2']); ?><br></td> #can do it automatically?
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Is that anyone can help me?

Thanks alots

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` or `PDO::FETCH_NUM` instead of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, please see [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) fro more details

Answer (score 0):

You could use `foreach`:

```
    echo '<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>'; 
               // write header
               foreach ($result[0] as $key => $value) {
                   echo "<th>".ucfirst($key)."</th>";
               }
               echo '</tr>
        </thead><tbody>';

               // loop for row 
               foreach ($result as $item) {
               echo "<tr>";
               // loop for column
               foreach ($item as $value) {
                   echo '<td class="wrap">'. $value . "</td>\n";
               }                        
               echo "</tr>\n";
               }
               echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Maybe you are looking for a more simple example:

```
echo '<table><tr>'; 
// loop for all columns in the 2. row
foreach ($row[1] as $key => $value) {
    echo '<td>' . $row[1][$key].'</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: Hi All I mean when we return result $result[0],  $result[1], ... Automatic, so when there was 100 columns in php can automatic fetch the result without declare and set one by one. It is possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. $result[0] returns the first row with all columns. in a foreach loop "$key
" gives you the Name of each column. did you try the code?

Comment: Hi Max, I've already try. But I've solve this question, later i'll update the answer. Thank you for your attention, support and concern.

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "";
while ($rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
#print_r($rows);
foreach ($rows as $array => $row) {
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($row as $col => $cell) {
echo "<td width='180px'>". $cell ."</td>";
}

}
echo "</tr></table>";
}
```